# ASP.net - C# - How to make it run faster ajaxToolkit : ToolkitScriptManager

Tags: asp.net, performance, optimization, toolkitscriptmanager

I am using ajaxToolkit for my website. I want to make it run faster.

ASP.net Netframework 4.0 - C# - Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

The below config is my current config. Waiting your further suggestions.

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server"  
ID="SC1" ScriptMode="Release" 
LoadScriptsBeforeUI="false" 
EnablePartialRendering="true" 
CombineScripts="true"   />
```

Comment: Didn't you ask that yesterday?

Comment: yes and deleted it. i think there is no way to bump questions right ?

Answer (score 1):

To optimize the ASP.NET AJAX in our web application, first of all, we need to make sure the Compression and Caching is enabled in web.config:

```
<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
<scriptResourceHandler enableCompression=“true” enableCaching=“true”/>
</scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

If you are using ASP.NET 3.5 with SP1, there is a more powerful tool to combining the Script file – CompositeScript.

Reference : [ASP.NET Ajax Performance](http://lancezhang.wordpress.com/2008/11/15/aspnet-ajax-performance/)

Comment: also checked the page you linked. it adds manually each one of the scripts for combining. that is impossible. i can not know which scripts will be provided and also a lot of mess code.